# Django 'non-keyword arg after keyword arg',

Tags: django

I'm designing a student database and I received this error 'str' object is not callable.
I can't find the location of  the error  so I'll paste my small app.Thank you.

```
 TypeError at /school/
 'str' object is not callableRequest Method: GET 
 Request URL: http://tafe.pythonanywhere.com/school/ 
 Django Version: 1.3.5 
 Exception Type: TypeError 
 Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable 
 Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response 
 1.                    for middleware_method in self._view_middleware:1.                        response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)1.                        if response:1.                            break1.1.                if response is None:1.                    try:
  111.                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
```

My models.py

```
  from django.db import models
  from django.contrib import admin
  class Student(models.Model):
          first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
          last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      age = models.BigIntegerField()
      body = models.TextField()

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.first_name
```

My views.py

```
  from mysite.school.models import student
  from django.shortcut import render_to_response
  from django.http import HttpResponse

  def index(request):
          students = Student.objects.all()
          render_to_response('index.html',{'students':students})
```

My index.html

```
Student Database
{% if students %}
<ul>
    {% for student in students %}
    <li>{{ student }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

my urls

```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns,include , url 
  from django.contrib import admin
  from mysite.school.views import index
  admin.autodiscover()
  urlpatterns = patterns ('',
url(r'^$','index'),
  )
```

Comment: Your syntax needs some help in regards to classes and properties. I've edited your post to reflect proper capitalization.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you certain this is the view being called?

Comment: In your `index` view, you return a dictionary with "student" (singular), but you use "students" (plural) everywhere else.

Comment: student must be students

Comment: @Brandon I noticed your edit introduced the bug mentioned. Made another edit to correct.

Comment: okay I got it fix but I still get that error

Comment: @donkeyboy72 You'll need to have and `{% endfor %}` somewhere. It looks like you'll want that right after the `<li>` and the `{% endif %}` should be moved after the closing `</ul>`.

Comment: @donkeyboy72 You're also not using the HttpResponse import...is there another view that does? If so, and that's the one trowing the exception, we need to see that code.

Comment: Also, please add your urls.py to your question.

Comment: The error above is stating about your url, I think you must post it to in your question

Comment: Alright , I posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your urls.py. It should be:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.school.views import index

admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^$', index),
)
```

To save yourself some typing, I would do:

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('mysite.school.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

which is what I think you were attempting to do in the first place. Hence the error 'str' object isn't callable.

Comment: thank you brandon . What does local variable student reference before assignment mean?

Comment: That means that you're attempting to reference a variable that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: No, it's not. I'll edit it to be correct for the given context.

Comment: thank you brandon . I'm trying to display all the students first name

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code. The Django template language will render the `__unicode__` for model instances if you simply reference the object. So there's no need to return `student.first_name`, when that will automatically be called for you.

Comment: Not to be rude, but it sounds like a walk through the tutorials at: http://djangobook.com/ would be good for you.

Comment: It certainly helps :) Of all of the programming languages I know, Python is by far my favorite, and it's very easy to learn, especially when compared to C#, Java, Scala or even Ruby, imo. The more Python you know, the better your Django applications will be.